# Password protected PDF/Excel reports using SQL Reporting services

Tags: sql, reporting-services, password-protection

I am generating a reports using SQL Reporting services 2005. I need to protect the protect the reports(pdf and excel) with the password while the user is exporting the report to to excel or pdf.

Is there any way to protect the report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't do this from the provided PDF rendering extension from SSRS 2005 (either from the web UI or programmatically from the SSRS web services). You can, however, create your own rendering extension that could provide this functionality. Here are some links that might help get you started:

[Introducing Rendering Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154606(SQL.90).aspx)
[Microsoft SQL Server 2005: Reporting Services](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/reporting-services.aspx)

You could take a COTS library, some open-source code, or your own custom code that can create password-protected PDF files, then wrap that into a custom rendering extension for SSRS 2005. In my opinion, however, this would be a relatively difficult task. A quick Google search didn't give me any obvious rendering extensions for sale that might provide the functionality you're looking for.